# Creating nested attributes through HATBM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I want to create a nested form for my application through HATBM

My Models are

Study => has_many :samples

Sample => has_many :expts

Expt => has_one :run

in my Studies - new view I have

```
<% form_for @study do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :study_Title %>
    <%= f.text_field :study_title, :size => 20 %><br \>
    <% for sample in Sample.find(:all) %>

        <div>
          <%= check_box_tag "study[sample_ids][]", sample.id, @study.samples.include?(sample) %>
          <%= sample.name %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <p><center><%= submit_tag "Next" %></center></p>
<% end %>
```

and in the Studies Controller

```
def create
    @study = Study.new(params[:study])
    if current_user.id?
       # Put the current user_id in the study.user_id
        @study.user_id = current_user.id
    end 
    if @study.save
      redirect_to :controller => "samples", :action => "add_sample_details", :method => "post", :id => @study.id
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end 
  end
```

In my add_sample_details action in the sample controller

```
 def add_sample_details
    @study = Study.find(params[:id])  
    @samples = Sample.find(:all, :joins => :study, :conditions => { :studies => { :id => @study.id } })
  end
```

I am unable to create sample attributes to update its records as well as unable to create new expt records for the specific samples

```
<% form_for @samples do |f| %>
    sample fields
and then 
            <% f.fields_for :expts do |f_expts| %>
            <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error "undefined method `sample_sample_path' for #"

Please could some tell me where I am creating a mistake.

Cheers